# Simplicial density function simultaneously defined for hyperbolic and spherical space (Kellerhals, 1998)

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, spherical-geometry, sphere-packing

I am confused about the proof of Corollary 4.2 in ["Ball Packings in Spaces of Constant Curvature and the Simplicial Density Function"](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/crll.1998.1998.issue-494/crll.1998.006/crll.1998.006.xml). The point of confusion is equation 4.3, where Kellerhals states that "the simplicial density $d_n(\alpha): [\alpha_n^\infty, \frac{\pi}{2}] \to \mathbb{R}$ is well-defined simultaneously for spherical, hyperbolic, and Euclidean geometries". Here $\alpha$ is the dihedral angle (or half the dihedral angle, using some authors' definition).

First, a regular simplex with dihedral angle $\alpha$ is realizable in exactly one of hyperbolic, euclidean, and spherical space. So I assume she means that the densities $d_n(\alpha)$ have natural analytic expressions in spherical and hyperbolic geometry, which can both be extended and which when extended are both equal. This looks like what she's computing immediately below equation 4.3.

Second, in Corollary 4.2 it reads "By means of (4.3) it suffices to prove the assertion for $\alpha \in (\alpha_n^\infty, \alpha_n^0)$." This is the range for hyperbolic space (and monotonicity was verified here by Marshalls). I cannot understand why this is sufficient to prove monotonicity of the density function everywhere in $[\alpha_n^\infty, \frac{\pi}{2}]$. Perhaps it is as simple as Kellerhals makes it look?

Thanks for any help.